# Can I open a php file in textedit on mac

Tags: php

I created a php file in TextEdit and when I click on GetInfo for the document, I see my php code in the preview screen, but when I open the file in TextEdit, I only see a blank white TextEdit screen. As a result, I can't edit my .php homework in TextEdit. Everything on google suggests TextEdit is the way I can create and view php files without paying a licensing fee, and although I already switched to sublime, I'm still curious about TextEdit.

Is this just something that TextEdit doesn't allow for?

Comment: You may have to just use another text editor. I ran into this exact same problem.